# Rewriting a less than or equal to equation with multiple absolute values

Tags: linear-algebra, absolute-value

So I have the following equation where a is a constant

$$|(x_1 - a)| + |(x_2 - a)| \leq 2$$

Can I rewrite this as the following:  $$|(x_1 - 2a + x_2)| \leq 2$$

Comment: No, you can't.  Taking $a=0$ note that $(x_1,x_2)=(100,-100)$ satisfies the second inequality.

Comment: Conceptually simplest approach is to write down four cases depending on the sign. You should be able to weave the inequalities back together to get fewer than 4.

Comment: Geometrically, draw a diamond centered at $(a,a)$ in the plane with diagonals of length $4$.

Comment: I got the following 4 inequalities 

$$(x_1 - a) + (x_2-a) \leq 2 \\
(x_1 - a) - (x_2-a) \leq 2 \\
-(x_1 - a) + (x_2-a) \leq 2\\
-(x_1 - a) - (x_2-a) \leq 2   $$ 

So ultimately, these can be weaved back together to get one equation?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly the first inequality implies the second, by an application of the triangle inequality: if the first holds then
$$|(x_1-2a+x_2)| = |(x_1-a)+(x_2-a)| \le |(x_1-a)| + |(x_2-a)| \le 2
$$
And sometimes just one direction of implication is what you actually need in proofs.

But when you reverse the direction of the triangle inequality what you get is not generally true. And therefore, when you reverse the direction of the implication, and ask whether the second inequality implies the first, the answer is "no", as shown in the comments.